# Finding squarefree divisors of a number in C

Tags: c, recursion, nlp-question-answering

The requirement is to list all divisors different from 1 of a given number that are not themselves divisible by a perfect square.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, temp;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            temp = sqrt(i);
            if (temp * temp != i)
                printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I give input as 20, then I get `1 2 4 5 10 20`. I have eliminated all the numbers which are perfect square ie: `4`.

Now, I'm having `1 2 5 10 20`. Here I don't have to consider `1` that means I'll have `2 5 10 20`.

Now, at last, I have to eliminate all those numbers which are divisible by a perfect square, how do I do that?

example: `20` will be eliminated because 4 x 5 = 20 and 4 is a perfect square.

Expected output: `2 5 10`

Comment: Very good. What is the problem?

Comment: in the result 20 is appearing but 20 = 4*5 and 4 is a perfect square so I have to eliminate all those numbers which have a similar case...

Comment: Where is 3,7,11,13,17 and 19 went?those neither not perfect square nor divisible by perfect square?

Comment: those are not the factors of 20... read the description above carefully.

Comment: You never mention anything about factors. You only mention numbers divisible by a perfect square.

Comment: You have shown some code and some partial description. What is your problem? If your code fails, you need to tell us in which way it fails.

Comment: If you are given a number N and simply want to know if it is square free, you can use this method. For example 20 = 2^2 + 4^2 = 2^2(1+2^2)=2^2*5. So 20 is not square free.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064068/can-the-sum-of-two-squares-be-used-to-determine-if-a-number-is-square-free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find a divisor `i` for `n`, you should remove higher powers of `i` from `n` to prevent multiples of powers of `i` from being found later in the scan:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i;

    if (scanf("%i", &n) == 1) {
        for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                printf("%d ", i);
                while (n % (i * i) == 0)
                    n /= i;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm is still quite slow for large primes. A faster method would first find the prime factors in **O(sqrt(N))** and print all combinations of the prime factors, but the list would not necessarily be produced in increasing order.

Considering this:

- a 32-bit number has at most **9** distinct prime factors:

  **29!! = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 = 6469693230**
- there are **2<sup>n</sup> - 1** possible combinations of **n** factors.
- all possible prime factors and square free divisors can be collected in rather small arrays, the latter can be sorted and printed.

Here is a much faster version for 32-bit `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sort_int(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    int i1 = *(const int *)p1;
    int i2 = *(const int *)p2;
    return (i1 > i2) - (i1 < i2);
}

int main() {
    int primes[9], divs[1 << 9];
    int i, j, n, p, np, nd;

    if (scanf("%i", &n) == 1) {
        np = 0;
        for (p = 2; p <= n / p; p++) {
            if (n % p == 0) {
                primes[np++] = p;
                while (n % p == 0)
                    n /= p;
            }
        }
        if (n > 1) {
            primes[np++] = n;
        }
        nd = 1 << np;
        for (i = 1; i < nd; i++) {
            divs[i] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < np; j++) {
                if (i & (1 << j))
                    divs[i] *= primes[j];
            }
        }
        qsort(divs, nd, sizeof(*divs), sort_int);
        for (i = 1; i < nd; i++) {
            printf("%d ", divs[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

64-bit `int` can be supported with a maximum number of prime factors at `15` instead of `9`, still acceptable for automatic storage.

Answer (score 0):

You have one evident problem and another possible one.

The evident one is that with

```
    temp = sqrt(i);
    if(temp*temp != i)
```

you (try to) test whether `i` **is** a perfect square, not if it is divisible by a perfect square. That is the reason why your code does not eliminate 20 which is indeed divisible by 4 but is not a perfect square itself.

The possible one if that `sqrt` returns a double value, and floating point is known to be [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3545273) (or more exactly to not always be exact...). So I would not be surprized that your test sometimes returns a wrong result.

What can be done: first *round* the resul of `sqrt` instead of (possibly) truncate it: `temp = sqrt(i) + .5;`
And do test whether `i` is divisible by a perfect square:

```
if (n%i == 0)
{
    int ok = 1;
    for (temp=2; temp < sqrt(i) + .5; temp++) {
        if (i % (temp * temp) == 0) {
            ok = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ok) printf("%d ",i);
}
```